# Custom field for background color for every category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a Custom field for background color for every category in Wordpress, anyone have any idea?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You need to have a metabox with meta field for category taxonomy's hex color. Look into Advance Custom Fields plugin or CMB2 class if you are ok with php coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put below code in functions.php file of your theme for admin side.

```
<?php
add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'add_background_color_field');
add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'edit_background_color_field');
add_action('edit_term', 'save_background_color_field');
add_action('create_term', 'save_background_color_field');

function add_background_color_field() {

    echo '<div class="form-field">
        <label for="category_background_color">Background Color</label>
        <input type="text" name="category_background_color" id="category_background_color" value="" />
        <p class="description">Category Background Color.</p>
        </div>';
}

function save_background_color_field($term_id) {
    if(isset($_POST['category_background_color']))
        update_option('cat_background_color'.$term_id, $_POST['category_background_color']);
}

function edit_background_color_field($category) {
    $background_color = get_option('cat_background_color'.$category->term_id);
    echo '<tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="category_background_color">Background Color</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="category_background_color" id="category_background_color" value="'.$background_color.'" />
            <p class="description">Category Background Color.</p>
        </td>
        </tr>';
}
?>
```

Use below code for front end.

```
<?php 
        $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
        $background_color = get_option('cat_background_color'.$cat_id);
?>
```

Use $background_color variable value wherever you want to use category background color in your archive.php or category.php file.

Comment: Your code is perfect and it is working fine on Admin side but not working on frontend, it seems i make some mistake, please help me little bit more so i can implement this, @Below is my code which i am using

Comment: <?php 
    $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'id',
      'hide_empty'=> 0,
      'child_of' => 1, //Child From Boxes Category 
  ); 
    $categories = get_categories($args);
     foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>  <h3 style="color: #<?php echo $background_color; ?>;"><?php echo $cat->name ?></h3>  <?php } ?>

Comment: Use this code :
<?php 
     $args = array('orderby' => 'id', 'hide_empty'=> 0, 'child_of' => 1);
     $categories = get_categories($args); 
     foreach ($categories as $cat) 
     { 
      $background_color = get_option('cat_background_color'.$cat->term_id);
     ?> 
      <h3 style="color: #<?php echo $background_color; ?>;"><?php echo $cat->name ?></h3> 
     <?php 
     } 
     ?>

Comment: @php-team Doesn't work on the home page archives for post excerpts. https://stackoverflow.com/users/4094161/php-team

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advanced Custom Fields plugin, and then get category color field value in function. Write style tag, use body class, and display add attach that function to wp_head.